# Silverlight Dynamic Data

Tags: silverlight-4.0, .net-4.0, dynamic-data

I wondered if anyone knows if Microsoft is planning to do a **Dynamic Data** framework for Silverlight like they’ve got for ASP.NET? Does a non Microsoft framework like this already exist?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I want to build forms over data applications as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your goal is data applications fast. Have a look at [XAML Power Toys](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/xaml-power-toys/) combined with [RIA Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707344(VS.91).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight has a support of [Microsoft RIA WCF Services](http://silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/), and I think this pattern some kinde of analog of Dynamic Data.